# Refresh gridview without loading entire page.If It is Possible With Ajax then please Teach that process

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gridview, webforms

How to Refresh only one part of page without loading entire page like i have gridview in my page that shows data of table when I click "Display Button" but If I update table same time  with update button without Loading page and then i click display button.Gridview does not  shows updated table.

If it is possible with ajax let me know how or let me know page where I can learn this thing only.not entire ajax

Comment: We need to see your view and controller. What have you tried already?

Comment: @HTX9 Cant  Image Dont have privilege I'm new here.. i have three button insert update and display().in click event of display button (Gridview2.Visible=true;) .when After inserting data Into Table i click on display to check whether  data is updated or  not Gridview get visible. But if i insert another data same time without loading page,Data will be inserted Into table But If i click on Display Button Gridview Not refreshed until i load entire page again

Comment: I can't understand please elaborate more.

Comment: @EmadMokhtar  how to refresh section of a page like particular gridview table or like facebook comment section

Answer (score 0):

To do partial PostBacks "efresh section of a page" you can use UpdatePanel and you can define which control with which event will raise the partial postbacks, for example here I placed GridView1 inside UpdatePanel so any event raised by the GridView will do partial postback and in `<Triggers>` I've define Click event of btnSubmit button control to raise partial postbacks also, notice that btnSubmit is outside UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Button Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Comp_CompanyId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comp_CompanyId" SortExpression="Comp_CompanyId">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comp_CompanyId") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCompany_Id" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comp_CompanyId") %>'
                            NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Comp_CompanyId","Persons.aspx?CompanyId={0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_Name" HeaderText="Comp_Name" SortExpression="Comp_Name"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_Type" HeaderText="Comp_Type" SortExpression="Comp_Type"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_Status" HeaderText="Comp_Status" SortExpression="Comp_Status"></asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CRMConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [Comp_CompanyId], [Comp_Name], [Comp_Type], [Comp_Status] FROM [Company]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```